# Temporary use lining (new style) numbers when default is oldstyle numbers?

Tags: oldstylenums, kpfonts, liningnums

I'd like to use `oldstylenums` by default. Now I do it with package [kpfonts](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/kpfonts). But sometimes I need to use lining numbers here and there, for example with capital letter stuff, like ISO 9000. Is there an easy way like with a macro `\newstylenums{123}`?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[oldstylenums]{kpfonts} 
\begin{document}
Numbers 123456789 are oldstyle. BUT 123456789 SHOULD BE NEWSTYLE!
\end{document}
```

And is there a general solution or does it depend on the font package in use?

Comment: If you use oldstyle numerals, I suggest using small caps for acronyms.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Are there any general guidelines for old style figure and smallcap usage? (Yes, I'm ordering "Elements of Typographic Style"). You'd prefer ISO9000 written with smallcaps+old style figures?

Comment: There's no “law” about this. It much depends on the document you're typesetting and the frequency of digits and acronyms. Be as generic as possible by defining appropriate macros, so you can easily compare results.

Comment: Yes, my plan is to use macros for this kind of acronyms having both letters and numbers. I think it will be either capitals+lining or smallcaps+oldstyle. Both look good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command your looking for is called `\classicstylenums`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[oldstylenums]{kpfonts}
\begin{document}
Numbers 123456789 are oldstyle. BUT \classicstylenums{123456789} SHOULD BE NEWSTYLE!
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, works perfectly! Didn't know about that command.

Comment: I have no idea, why that command is undocumented...

Comment: Are there similar commands for controlling figure tabularity/proportionality?

Comment: AFAIK not possible with `kpfonts`. There is [`tabfigures`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tabfigures/tabfigures.pdf) which supports fonts with pdflatex (using [`fontaxes`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/fontaxes/fontaxes.pdf)) and lua-, xelatex (using [`fontspec`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/fontspec/fontspec.pdf))